# VS Code: best practice for file shortcuts/aliases/favourites/bookmarks

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is a query from a beginner wondering about best practice suggestions - I have a system for myself but am wondering what other more experienced people do.

My desired end result is a way to access a number of specified files which are in multiple different places within a working directory.

My specific example is with Django, where my HTML, CSS & JS files are spread in different directories (such as Template & Static). What I'm imagining is a way to quickly access/open all three files, even if they're in different locations - possibly creating a "ProjectFoo" folder, then within that folder are links/shortcuts/aliases to the required files.

I'm currently using the Favorites (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kdcro101.favorites) which covers the majority of my uses, and there are also these alternatives:

- VSCode-Favorites: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=howardzuo.vscode-favorites
- Project Manager: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.project-manager

...but am wondering aobut recommendations regarding best practice - what is the usual way people go about this, as it seems (to me at least) that it might be a common workflow issue.

Thanks!

Rich